# list of dictionaries processing - readability and complexity

Tags: python, list-comprehension, code-readability

I have basic question about comprehension.
There is list of dicts where values are lists, it looks like this:

```
listionary = [{'path': ['/tmp/folder/cat/number/letter', '/tmp/folder/hog/char/number/letter', '/tmp/folder/hog/number/letter', '/etc'], 
'mask': True, 
'name': 'dict-1'}, 
{'path': ['/tmp/folder/dog/number-2/letter-4', '/tmp/folder/hog-00/char/number-1/letter-5', '/tmp/folder/cow/number-2/letter-3'], 
'mask': True, 
'name': 'dict-2'}, 
{'path': ['/tmp/folder/dog_111/number/letter', '/tmp/folder/ant/char/number/letter', '/tmp/folder/hen/number/letter'], 
'mask': True, 
'name': 'dict-3'}]
```

What I need is to get from list-type values every unique animal.
Animal is always between **tmp/folder/** and next **/**.
What I did:

```
import re
flat_list = [item for sublist in [i['path'] for i in listionary] for item in sublist]
animals = list(set([re.search('folder/([a-z]+)', elem).group(1) for elem in flat_list if 'tmp' in elem]))
```

It might be also compressed into one line, but it is quite complicated and unreadable:

```
animals = list(set([re.search('folder/([a-z]+)', elem).group(1) for elem in [item for sublist in [i['path'] for i in listionary] for item in sublist] if 'tmp' in elem]))
```

Is there any golden rule(e.g. zen of python) about size of comprehension? 
How can I make it better? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I, for one, am not enamored with *one-liners*, sometimes they make sense, sometimes they don't. Readability should be a consideration.  Will you understand it tomorrow?

Comment: Please take the time to read [ask].

Comment: comprehensions are subject to the same 79 or 119 (based on preference) column guideline, and I'd look at breaking it up if you start exceeding that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*How can I make it better?*

1. have someone else read it. ✓
2. use functions to encapsulate more complex operations
3. don't nest loops on the same line

Here's how I would break down the last two points..

```
def get_animals(d):
    animals = []
    for item in d['path']:
        if item.startswith('/tmp/folder/'):
            animals.append(item[12:item.find('/',12)])
    return animals

animals = set()
for d in dlist:
    animals.update(get_animals(d))
animals = list(animals)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
listionary = [{'path': ['/tmp/folder/cat/number/letter', '/tmp/folder/hog/char/number/letter', '/tmp/folder/hog/number/letter', '/etc'], 
'mask': True, 
'name': 'dict-1'}, 
 {'path': ['/tmp/folder/dog/number-2/letter-4', '/tmp/folder/hog-00/char/number-1/letter-5', '/tmp/folder/cow/number-2/letter-3'], 
'mask': True, 
'name': 'dict-2'}, 
{'path': ['/tmp/folder/dog_111/number/letter', '/tmp/folder/ant/char/number/letter', '/tmp/folder/hen/number/letter'], 
'mask': True, 
'name': 'dict-3'}]
import re
from itertools import chain
animals = list(set(chain.from_iterable([[re.findall("/tmp/folder/(.*?)/", b)[0] for b in i["path"] if re.findall("/tmp/folder/(.*?)/", b)] for i in listionary])))
```

Output:

```
['hog', 'hog-00', 'cow', 'dog_111', 'dog', 'cat', 'ant', 'hen']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it more readable by adding newlines and indentation. I stopped at the line with `item for sublist...` because I didn't understand the code logic, but presumably you can add more newlines in there.

```py
animals = list(
    set([
            re.search('folder/([a-z]+)', elem).group(1) for elem in [
                item for sublist in [i['path'] for i in listionary] for item in sublist
            ]
            if 'tmp' in elem
    ])
)
```

That said, I would consider something like this to be much more readable:

```py
def animal_name_from_path(path):
    return re.search('folder/([a-z]+)', path).group(1)

def is_animal_path(path):
    return '/tmp' in path

def deduplicate(L):
    return list(set(L))

path_list = []
for item in listionary:
    path_list.extend(item['path'])

animals = deduplicate([animal_name_from_path(path) for path in path_list if is_animal_path(path)])
```

One rule of thumb applied here is that any concept should have a name. In your original code, `item for sublist in [i['path'] for i in listionary] for item in sublist` is very hard to understand because it's unclear what `item` and `i` are supposed to be. In this new block it's much clearer that you're just flattening a list of paths. The animal name identification code is much easier to understand once all concepts are named. Here I may have taken it to an extreme - you can find your own happy equilibrium that you find the most readable.

Answer (score 0):

Shortened solution:

```
animals = set(re.search(r'/folder/([a-z]+)', p).group(1) for d in listionary for p in d['path'] if '/tmp' in p)
print(animals)
```

The output:

```
{'hog', 'cat', 'dog', 'cow', 'hen', 'ant'}
```